Getting 401 in Spotify Web playback sdk
I'm building a React app using Spotify Web Playback sdk. I was following this guide here, but I'm struggling to refresh the token using Authorization Code flow.
I know Spotify uses refresh_token to get a fresh token (expiration is 1h), but I'm not getting how it works in practice.
This is my auth callback:
router.get("/auth/callback", (req, res) => {
  console.log("spotify callback");
  var code = req.query.code;

  var authOptions = {
    url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    form: {
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3001/spotify/auth/callback",
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "Basic " +
        Buffer.from(
          process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID +
            ":" +
            process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET
        ).toString("base64"),
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    json: true,
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log("auth ok", body);
      access_token = body.access_token;
      refresh_token = body.refresh_token;
      res.redirect("http://localhost:8080");
    } else {
      console.log("ERROR AUTH", error, response);
    }
  });
});

I'm returning both tokens to the UI app with this:
router.get("/auth/token", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    access_token: access_token,
    refresh_token: refresh_token,
  });
});

So far the UI part is basically a react component that calls /auth/token api and, if token is present, it renders the player. Everything works good except that after 60 minutes I would need to reauthenticate.
How can I ask a fresh token? Do I need to calculate the expiration in UI side and, if >1h, request a new token?

Ensure that the Spotify account being used for playback is a Premium account, as the Web Playback SDK requires it.
or
Check Token Expiry
or
Check Your Access Token

I can confirm it’s a premium account. What do you mean with check your access token?

You need to create a new route that will be responsible for refreshing the access token using the refresh token.

When the access token expires, the front-end should make a request to this new endpoint to get a fresh access token.

So, the flow is: check token expiration and if expired call the new route to get the fresh token, right?
